# Using scipy.stats.chisquare with masked arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy, chi-squared

I need to calculate the chi-squared fit to a set of arrays (`observed` and `expected`). The arrays are the same size, but some of the elements of `expected` are `None` because I don't know the expected value.

I would like to use the `scipy.stats.chisquare` to calculate the chi-squared fit of the data. Since some of my data is `None`, I get the error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'float' and 'NoneType'
```

I've tried to get around this by only including the data that is not `None`

```py
import numpy.ma
import scipy.stats

expected = [None, 2,3,4]
observed = [1,2.2,3.3,4.4]

expMasked = numpy.ma.masked_where(expected == None, expected)
obsMasked = numpy.ma.masked_where(expected == None, observed)

chi2 = scipy.stats.chisquare(obsMasked, f_exp=expMasked)
```

This just give me the same error.

**How can I use the `scipy.stats.chisquare` function with my data?**

Comment: `expMasked` still has `None` in it. You need to use `numpy.ma.masked_where(expected == np.array(None), expected)` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it seems logical that `numpy.ma.masked_where(expected == None, expected)` would in fact mask `expected` where `None` occurs, `numpy.ma` does not recognize `None` as comparable to `expected`, so `None` must be cast to an `np.array`. Your code will work like this

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats

expected = [None, 2,3,4]
observed = [1,2.2,3.3,4.4]

expMasked = np.ma.masked_where(expected == np.array(None), expected)
obsMasked = np.ma.masked_where(observed == np.array(None), observed)

expMasked[expMasked.mask] = (VALUE YOU WANT MASKED VALUES TO BE REPLACED WITH)
obsMasked[obsMasked.mask] = (VALUE YOU WANT MASKED VALUES TO BE REPLACED WITH)

chi2 = scipy.stats.chisquare(np.array(obsMasked), f_exp=np.array(expMasked))
```

Comment: @jlconlin You need to replace the masked value with something still. You can now do `expMasked[expMasked.mask] = 0` or whatever replacement value you want.

Comment: @jlconlin I edited the code. Sorry, I completely blanked on that the first time around